# ATSAMB B11 BLE Pressure

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, pressure, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

Hi I am developing an application where an ATSAMB11 device has to send pressure data (from 0 to 6 bar with 5mbar steps) through BLE. I was just wondering if I should implement a custom service and characteristics or I can use the blood pressure service that is already implemented for atsamb11. I am asking because if I use the blood pressure service, it would be much easier as it is furnished with examples and I could write my program over it. Whereas if I have to create my custom service, I don't know where to start and what I need to write. (I precise that it's the first time that I'm working on BLE)

Another option would be to send the data through the custom serial chat service(which is also implemented and have an exemple), but I think that doing so is not the right way to use BLE. Indeed, why would everyone bother about different services and profiles if they could send anything through custom serial chat.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the standard blood pressure service, do that. Custom services are only used if there is no matching standard profile or the standard profile lacks some functionality one wants.